# asp.net Website Open XLSX File In Excel, Directly From IE Browser?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ms-office, office-interop

I'm working on a very old asp.net web site. The code generates a response as standard html content but uses a neat little trick where the Response is tweaked in the code-behind page like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

This causes a prompt to appear in the users' browser, and when he or she chooses "Open", the content then opens directly into Microsoft Excel. No Interop libraries are added to the project, and no Excel content is actually being generated - just html.

Requirements now state that all Microsoft Office-related content must be set to the openXML format (*.xlsx, *.docx, etc.) rather than the much older native formats (*.xls, *.doc, etc.).

Now it is obvious that the content generated by asp.net is not really even Office content - it's just html tables with data that is opened in Excel as a matter of convenience for sorting, etc. But the configuration that enables this also causes the initial "Open", "Save" etc. prompt to display a filename as "myfile.xls"...and so this is not going to be acceptable.

When I update the ContentType to agree with the newer openXML standard, the filename does indeed change to "myfile.xlsx". BUT...for some reason this causes IE to suddenly not allow the file to open in Excel anymore when "Open" is clicked. Instead, after clicking on "Open," I now get another prompt at the bottom of the browser window with "Save", "Save as" and a DISABLED/GRAYED-OUT "Save and open" options.

What is a good strategy to update the displayed "XLS" filename to "XLSX", while preserving the current functionality of having the Response content to automatically open in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: what is the version of Office in the machine that is trying to open the xlsx file?

Comment: thanks for your response despite the difficulty of making a comment :) I suppose the contenttype you were referring to is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet?